# Related to Google Geolocation API

Tags: java, google-api

I am unable to find the specific API in the Google Geolocation API documentation that provides 'sublocality_level_1' information based on a city name. I want to store all the 'sublocality_level_1' details for a given city in my database for a project. I have checked the documentation for the Google Geolocation API but couldn't find the relevant information. If anyone knows the answer, please reply.